# Read USB serial port data with web serial api in javascript

Tags: javascript, serial-port, webusb, com-port, web-serial-api

-I work on temperature and humidity reading device development. we have our own temperature and humidity reader device(USB-based COM(serial) port device). currently, we fetch the with standalone software which uses a virtual com port drive to communicate with the device. but, I want to read these recorded data in my web app using "web serial API".

when writing code to read that data, I am not able to fetch the data. I am following "https://web.dev/serial/" this article for reading data.

-should I use a virtual comport driver with web serial API to read the data or not?

so what can I do for reading usb com port device data with "web serial API".

--this is my code for write and read data.

```
<script>
class LineBreakTransformer {
      constructor() {
        this.chunks = "";
      }

      transform(chunk, controller) {
        this.chunks += chunk;
        const lines = this.chunks.split("\r\n");
        this.chunks = lines.pop();
        lines.forEach((line) => controller.enqueue(line));
      }

      flush(controller) {
        controller.enqueue(this.chunks);
      }
  }
async function onStartButtonClick() {
    try {
      const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
      console.log("req");
      await port.open({ baudRate: 19200,       
                        dataBits: 8,
                        stopBits: 1,
                        parity: "none",
                        flowControl: "none",
    });
    const {usbProductId, usbVendorId}=port.getInfo();
    document.getElementById("sdata").innerHTML=usbProductId+" "+ " <br>"+usbVendorId;
    
      console.log("opanning");
        
                        

                const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
                 console.log("true is");
                const data = new Uint8Array([0x32]); 
            
                await writer.write(data);
                console.log("succ");

        
            writer.releaseLock();

      while (port.readable) {
        
        const textDecoder = new TextDecoderStream();
        const readableStreamClosed = port.readable.pipeTo(textDecoder.writable);
        const reader = textDecoder.readable
        .pipeThrough(new TransformStream(new LineBreakTransformer()))
        .getReader();
        console.log("portreadable");

        try {
          while (true) {
            const { value, done } = await reader.read();
            if (done) {
              console.log("Canceled");
              break;
            }
            console.log("tryfun");
            console.log(value);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error: Read");
          console.log(error);
        } finally {
          reader.releaseLock();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error: Open");
      console.log(error);
    }

     
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a browser or environment that can use WebSerial? [Web Serial API](https://caniuse.com/web-serial), [serialport-binding-webserialapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport-binding-webserialapi) It would be better to add such detailed information.

Comment: it is a chrome browser.  I don't want to use nodejs, but using web Serial API(to communicate with USB-based serial port device)  which is inside chrome browser with javascript. here nothing role of nodejs.

Comment: In order to make it easier to get advice and answers, it is better to add information such as software and equipment/OS.

Comment: My comments are advice, not questions. Please refer to these help articles and try to improve your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please expand the question with more details about what you have tried and in what way fetching the data fails. The Web Serial API is usually the right choice for reading from a virtual COM port but working with any particular device requires knowledge about the data formats expected by and produced from the device. As the device manufacturer you are most likely to have this knowledge so the issue you have is probably with the code you've written using the Web Serial API. If you can share an example of that code we might be able to help you.

Comment: I have to pass the hex values as a command[0xcc,0xab,0xab](you can see in the image) step by step to the serial port device. then the device will match that command internally. if the commands are matched, then it will send hex values[ 4f 47 47 45 52 0d 0a]("LOGGER" string value of the hex)  in response to those commands. (i am using termite3.4 software to perform this task).  so, I want to perform this same task using web serial API.                                                          (i have edited my question with image and code ).

Comment: I’m looking to access a serial device that is connected to a usb converter. Is that what you are doing? Do you need to use the usb api or serial api?

Answer (score 1):

> should I use a virtual comport driver with web serial API to read the data or not?

The answer to your question is yes, whatever driver is installed that allows you to use the device for your stand-alone software should give you access to the device when using WebSerial.

My assumption is your browser is showing you a list of serial devices after calling `navigator.serial.requestPort()` and that you are able to select the intended device and click the Connect button.  If you are not seeing either the dialog or the device on the dialog, review Device Manager to better understand how the device needs to be accessed (e.g., maybe it requires WebUSB).

Your port.open only requires the baud, as the remaining values, 8N1, no hardware flow control, are the defaults.

```
await port.open({ baudRate: 19200 });
```

You may want to simplify your initial code to see what your device is actually returning after your write.  This code located on https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#rs-intro should help toward that end.

```
console.log(await readAllChunks(port.readable));

function readAllChunks(readableStream) {
  const reader = readableStream.getReader();
  const chunks = [];

  return pump();

  function pump() {
    return reader.read().then(({ value, done }) => {
      if (done) {
        return chunks;
      }

      chunks.push(value);
      return pump();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, why does "web serial API"  doesn't work on the android chrome browser?  does have any alternative for the android chrome browser?

Comment: The Web Serial API is available on all desktop platforms (Chrome OS, Linux, macOS, and Windows) in Chrome 89. See https://web.dev/serial/#browser-support
I'd recommend checking out https://web.dev/devices-introduction/#discover to see if your device supports either HID or USB.